# Are there any viable alternatives to the OOB RichHTMLField editor?

Tags: 2013, richhtmlfield

One of our customers is complaining about the poor quality of the built-in Rich field editor. FWIW, I'm also unimpressed by the quality of the editor, and would dearly love to have one at hand.

Do any such editors, either free or payed, exist?

Comment: In a previous place, I wired up TinyMCE to replace the SharePoint rich text editor, could probably be adapted for 2013, http://joshmccarty.com/2011/06/use-tinymce-as-the-rich-text-editor-in-sharepoint-forms/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/sharepoint-web-parts.aspx

Definitely not free, but won't break the bank either.  I've used this, the grid, and some of the other controls on different projects over the years.